# Adding JWT Bearer Authorization to NSwag 13

Tags: c#, .net-core, swagger, nswag

We were using NSwag 11 and trying to move to the 13th that seems to use quite different calls.

The old-style code looks kind of

```
public static class SwaggerServiceExtensions
{
    public static IServiceCollection AddSwaggerDocumentation(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerDoc("v1.0", new Info { Title = "Main API v1.0", Version = "v1.0" });

            c.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", new ApiKeyScheme
            {
                Description = "JWT Authorization header using the Bearer scheme. Example: \"Authorization: Bearer {token}\"",
                Name = "Authorization",
                In = "header",
                Type = "apiKey"
            });
        });

        return services;
    }

    public static IApplicationBuilder UseSwaggerDocumentation(this IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseSwagger();
        app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1.0/swagger.json", "Versioned API v1.0");

            c.DocExpansion("none");
        });

        return app;
    }
}
```

And now it feels that the library has changed significantly. So now I shall use *services.AddSwaggerDocument* and *app.UseSwaggerUi3*. And there is no more option like *SwaggerSecurityScheme* or *ApiKeyScheme*

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the following ?

```
services.AddOpenApiDocument(document => 
{
    document.DocumentName = "v1";
    document.PostProcess = d =>
    {
        d.Info.Version = "v1";
        d.Info.Title = "Main API v1.0";
    };

    document.AddSecurity("apikey", Enumerable.Empty<string>(), new OpenApiSecurityScheme
    {
        Description = "JWT Authorization header using the Bearer scheme. Example: \"Authorization: Bearer {token}\"",
        Type = OpenApiSecuritySchemeType.ApiKey,
        Name = "Authorization",
        In = OpenApiSecurityApiKeyLocation.Header
    });

    document.OperationProcessors.Add(
        new OperationSecurityScopeProcessor("bearer"));
});
```

with

```
app.UseSwaggerUi3(typeof(Startup).GetTypeInfo().Assembly, settings =>
{
        settings.DocumentPath = "/swagger/" + "v1" + "/swagger.json";
        settings.DocExpansion = "none";
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I would be able to check only a few days later.